# Access google container registry without the gcloud client

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-container-registry

I have a CoreOS docker host that I want to start running containers on, but when trying to use the docker command to fetch the image from the google container private registry (https://cloud.google.com/tools/container-registry/), I get a 403. I did some searching, but I'm not sure how to attach authentication (or where to generate the user+pass bundle to use with the docker login command).

Has anybody had any luck pulling from the google private containers? I can't install the gcloud command because coreos doesn't come with python, which is a requirement

```
docker run -p 80:80 gcr.io/prj_name/image_name
Unable to find image 'gcr.io/prj_name/image_name:latest' locally
Pulling repository gcr.io/prj_name/image_name
FATA[0000] HTTP code: 403
```

**Update**: after getting answers from @mattmoor and @Jesse:

The machine that I'm pulling from does have devaccess

```
curl -H 'Metadata-Flavor: Google' http://metadata.google.internal./computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/scopes
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore
----> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.admin
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/taskqueue
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

Additionally, I tried using the _token login method

```
jenkins@riskjenkins:/home/andre$ ACCESS_TOKEN=$(curl -H 'Metadata-Flavor: Google' 'http://metadata.google.internal./computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token' | cut -d'"' -f 4)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   142  100   142    0     0  14686      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 15777
jenkins@riskjenkins:/home/andre$ echo $ACCESS_TOKEN
**************(redacted, but looks valid)
jenkins@riskjenkins:/home/andre$ docker login -e not@val.id -u _token -p $ACCESS_TOKEN http://gcr.io
Login Succeeded
jenkins@riskjenkins:/home/andre$ docker run gcr.io/prj_name/image_name
Unable to find image 'gcr.io/prj_name/image_name:latest' locally
Pulling repository gcr.io/prj_name/image_name
FATA[0000] HTTP code: 403
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The Google Container Registry authentication scheme is to simply use:

```
username: '_token'
password: {oauth access token}
```

On Google Compute Engine you can login **without** gcloud with:

```
$ METADATA=http://metadata.google.internal./computeMetadata/v1
$ SVC_ACCT=$METADATA/instance/service-accounts/default
$ ACCESS_TOKEN=$(curl -H 'Metadata-Flavor: Google' $SVC_ACCT/token \
    | cut -d'"' -f 4)
$ docker login -e not@val.id -u '_token' -p $ACCESS_TOKEN https://gcr.io
```

**Update on {asia,eu,us,b}.gcr.io**

To access a repository hosted in a localized repository, you should login to the appropriate hostname in the above `docker login` command.

**Update on quotes around _token**

As of docker version 1.8, docker login requires the -u option to be in qoutes or start with a letter.

**Some diagnostic tips...**

Check that you have the Cloud Storage scope via:

```
$ curl -H 'Metadata-Flavor: Google' $SVC_ACCT/scopes
...
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
...
```

***NOTE:*** "docker pull" requires "read_only", but "docker push" requires "read_write".

To give this robot access to a bucket in another project, there are a few steps.

First, find out the VM service account (aka robot)'s identity via:

```
$ curl -H 'Metadata-Flavor: Google' $SVC_ACCT/email
1234567890@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

Next, there are three important ACLs to update:

1) Bucket ACL (needed to list objects, etc)

```
PROJECT_ID=correct-answer-42
ROBOT=1234567890@developer.gserviceaccount.com
gsutil acl ch -u $ROBOT:R gs://artifacts.$PROJECT_ID.appspot.com
```

2) Bucket Default ACL (template for future #3)

```
gsutil defacl ch -u $ROBOT:R gs://artifacts.$PROJECT_ID.appspot.com
```

3) Object ACLs  (only needed when the bucket is non-empty)

```
gsutil -m acl ch -R -u $ROBOT:R gs://artifacts.$PROJECT_ID.appspot.com
```

Part of why this isn't in our official documentation yet is that we want a better high-level story for it, but tl;dr we respect GCS ACLs.

Comment: This looks promising, I'll give it a shot tomorrow

Comment: FWIW, we require the GCS read scope for this to work.

You can check this with:
curl -H 'Metadata-Flavor: Google' http://metadata.google.internal./computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts
/default/scopes

Comment: The GCE instance does have devstorage read-only capabilities, and although login succeeded, I was unable to pull the image. I edited the original question with my attempts at both yours and @Jesse's suggestions. Let me know if you have any other suggestions

Comment: It looks like you have "http ://gcr.io" can you try https?

Comment: I tried doing the login with https but I got the same error

Comment: I just tested this on the coreos-beta-633-1-0-v20150401 image on GCE.

Aside from a line-break that stackoverflow added to my copy/paste, it worked for me.

I get a 403 before the login, I log in, I then pull successfully.

A few things to bear in mind:
1) access tokens expire
2) the VM must be in the same project (or the ACLs must have been updated accordingly)

Feel free to reach out to gcr-contact@google.com and I'm happy to discuss this a bit more synchronously to get this resolved.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'll contact you guys via email

Comment: Matt. I was able to get it to work. I spawned machines on an alternate project and was trying to access the project across ACLs. Thank you for the details -- I was wondering if this is anywhere in the  public documentation?

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now.  Not in our docs, but we respect Google Cloud Storage ACLs.  As the formatting of these comments sucks, I'll amend my answer with some instructions. :)

Comment: it worked for me, but this login token is SHORT LIVED TOKEN, you have to login for every session.

Answer (score 19):

The answers here deal with accessing docker from within a Google Compute Engine instance.

If you want to work with the Google Container Registry on a machine not in the Google Compute Engine (i.e. local) using vanilla docker you can [follow Google's instructions](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/auth).

The two main methods are using an access token or a JSON key file.

*Note that `_token` and `_json_key` are the actual values you provide for the username (`-u`)*

**Access Token**

```
$ docker login -e 1234@5678.com -u _token -p "$(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://gcr.io
```

**JSON Key File**

```
$ docker login -e 1234@5678.com -u _json_key -p "$(cat keyfile.json)" https://gcr.io
```

To create a key file you can follow these instructions:

1. Open the Credentials page.
2. To set up a new service account, do the following:

   - Click Add credentials > Service account.
   - Choose whether to download the service account's public/private key as a     standard P12 file, or as a JSON file that can be loaded by a Google API client library.
   - Your new public/private key pair is generated and downloaded to your machine; it serves as the only copy of this key. You are responsible for storing it securely.

You can [view Google's documentation on generating a key file here](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#serviceaccounts).

Comment: this answer you provided gave me some hope that I could get things working, after flushing a day or more down the drain trying to do something so simple as pushing an image up to the repo, but still no luck.

Comment: I DID IT!!! I think part of the problem is that gcr.io is so similar to grc.com, Steve Gibson/Security Now's website. Probably typo'd that many many times. When I finally got it right, the Access Token means worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

There are [two official ways](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication):

1. `$ docker login -e 1234@5678.com -u oauth2accesstoken -p "$(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://gcr.io`
2. `$ docker login -e 1234@5678.com -u _json_key -p "$JSON_KEY" https://gcr.io`

Note: The e-mail is not used, so you can put whatever you want in it.

Change `gcr.io` to whatever is your domain shown in your [Google Container Registry](https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images) (e.g. `eu.gcr.io`).

Option (1) only gives a temporary token, so you probably want option (2). To get that `$JSON_KEY`:

1. Go to [API Manager > Credentials](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_)
2. Click "Create credentials" > **Service account key**:

   - Service account: New service account

     - Name: Anything you want, like `Docker Registry (read-only)`
     - Role: Storage (scroll down) > **Storage Object Viewer**
   - Key type: **JSON**
3. Download as `keyfile.json`
4. `JSON_KEY=$(cat keyfile.json | tr '\n' ' ')`
5. Now you can use it.

Once logged in you can just run `docker pull`. You can also copy the updated `~/.dockercfg` to preserve the settings.

Comment: ```unknown shorthand flag: 'e' in -e
See 'docker login --help'.```

Comment: You saved my time, Able to login with first command.

Answer (score 1):

When you created your VM did you give it the necessary scopes in order to be able to read from the registry?

> gcloud compute instances create INSTANCE \
>       --scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write

If you did so no further authentication is required.

Comment: I dont think this is true, because  "If this flag is not provided, the following scopes are used: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write"   I'm pulling from the repo, so read_only should be enough, but I still get a  403

Answer (score 0):

There is an official [Google Container Registry Auth Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Google+Container+Registry+Auth+Plugin) published. You are welcome to try it and leave feedback/report issues.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out. I was able to get it to a good enough state by logging in to both the https://gcr and http://gcr endpoints with the access tokens. For some reason I needed to login to both

Comment: @Andre: Are you using Google Container Registry Auth Plugin with Docker Build Step plugin or other plugin? I am also a bit confused by your statement "logging into both the gcr and gcr endpoints". Can you clarify? If you are using Docker Build Step plugin with GCR auth plugin, then you need to add the provided credentials to each individual Docker Build Step command.

Answer (score -1):

I have developed a jenkins plugin that allows a slave running on GCE to login into google's registry using @mattmoor's solution. It might be useful to others. :)

It's available at https://github.com/Byclosure/gcr.io-login-plugin.

Comment: Please don't post link only answers as links may break