# Pull private docker images from Google Container Registry w/o gcloud

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, docker-compose, docker-registry, google-container-registry

I'm using shippable to push private docker images to the Google Container Registry that I then want to pull from either locally on a laptop, or inside an instance on the Google Compute Engine.

I know that the command `gcloud preview docker pull gcr.io/projectID/image-name` works, but I can't rely on gcloud being installed on every machine that someone may need to pull the image from.

If I run `docker-compose up -d` on my machine then I get the following error:

```
Pulling image gcr.io/projectID/image-name...
Pulling repository gcr.io/projectID/image-name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/compose/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.cli.main", line 31, in main
  File "/compose/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.cli.docopt_command", line 21, in sys_dispatch
  File "/compose/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.cli.command", line 27, in dispatch
  File "/compose/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.cli.docopt_command", line 24, in dispatch
  File "/compose/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.cli.command", line 59, in perform_command
  File "/compose/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.cli.main", line 464, in up
  File "/compose/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.project", line 208, in up
  File "/compose/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.service", line 214, in recreate_containers
  File "/compose/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.service", line 199, in create_container
  File "/compose/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.progress_stream", line 37, in stream_output
  File "/compose/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.progress_stream", line 50, in print_output_event
compose.progress_stream.StreamOutputError: Error: Status 403 trying to pull repository projectID/image-name: "Access denied."
```

Is there any way to authenticate or access the image with some form of OAuth or keys? I want to avoid having to install gcloud on every machine that will ever need to pull the image, and the images have to remain private.

I have tried `gcloud preview docker -a` but that is not the solution I'm looking for.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291576/access-google-container-registry-without-the-gcloud-client

Comment: Yes, and your solution works on the GCE (Thank you!), however I cannot apply it when running on a local machine. There is also the issue that I have to manually authenticate on every GCE instance that is created, which is not scalable.

Comment: Locally, you can use still use "docker login", but substitute "gcloud auth print-access-token" for the curl (or gcloud docker -a).

Comment: Regarding authentication, yes.  You might consider trying the container-vm image as your host image, it has a crontab that keeps these credentials up to date automatically (you don't need to use the manifest for this).  see: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/container_vms

Comment: have you figured how to do this? Using CoreOS here and no python, no gcloud option as i need to pull the images on the host.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access google container registry without the gcloud client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291576/access-google-container-registry-without-the-gcloud-client)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to work with the Google Container Registry on a machine not in the Google Compute Engine (i.e. local) using vanilla docker you can [follow Google's instructions](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/auth).

The two main methods are using an access token or a JSON key file.

*Note that `_token` and `_json_key` are the actual values you provide for the username (`-u`)*

**Access Token**

```
$ docker login -e 1234@5678.com -u _token -p "$(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://gcr.io
```

**JSON Key File**

```
$ docker login -e 1234@5678.com -u _json_key -p "$(cat keyfile.json)" https://gcr.io
```

To create a key file you can follow these instructions:

1. Open the Credentials page.
2. To set up a new service account, do the following:

   - Click Add credentials > Service account.
   - Choose whether to download the service account's public/private key as a     standard P12 file, or as a JSON file that can be loaded by a Google API client library.
   - Your new public/private key pair is generated and downloaded to your machine; it serves as the only copy of this key. You are responsible for storing it securely.

You can [view Google's documentation on generating a key file here](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#serviceaccounts).

Comment: Does `_json_key` come from json file? Any idea which field does it correspond to?

Comment: `_json_key` is a literal value. It's signaling to GCR what to expect from the `-p` flag.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the following then also it would work.

```
cat service-account.json | docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://gcr.io
```