# gcloud docker push reliability

Tags: docker, gcloud, docker-machine, google-container-registry

I have been having a lot of problems pushing images with `gcloud docker push` over the past few weeks. I've read through the many stack overflow discussions and github issues and workarounds but I haven't come across a solution to the inconsistency yet.

Typically I will attempt to push a container image or two. The first push will almost always fail with the following retry-until-timeout output:

[image]

I can only get around it with `gcloud auth login`. At most 5 minutes later I will attempt to push a second image, and will again see the retry-until-timeout issue. I will see this on every attempt until I `gcloud auth login` again.

Often I will have to manually retry several more times immediately after authenticating before the image is actually pushed.

1. Am I actually being logged out (I can still access pods and instances, etc with `kubectl` and `gcloud` machines)? If so, why is being logged out inconsistent and what does building docker containers do that it would invalidate my local gcloud session?
2. If not, why can't I `gcloud docker push` until I authenticate again? After that, why is this still inconsistent (I suspect it may have little or nothing to do with the real issue).
3. Is there a way to make pushing images on OSX with docker-machine and gcloud docker push reliable? Is there another way to get images to the cloud repository (preferably from the command line)?

`gcloud --version`

`alpha 2016.01.12
beta 2016.01.12
bq 2.0.18
bq-nix 2.0.18
core 2016.02.11
core-nix 2016.02.05
gcloud
gsutil 4.16
gsutil-nix 4.15
kubectl
kubectl-darwin-x86_64 1.1.7`

`docker --version`
`Docker version 1.10.1, build 9e83765`

`docker-machine --version`
`docker-machine version 0.6.0, build e27fb87`

virtualbox version 5.0.14 r105127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never faced the problems you mentioned with `gcloud docker`, but regarding your last point,

> Is there another way to get images to the cloud repository (preferably from the command line)?

it is indeed possible to push to the gcr.io repos without going through gcloud, e.g:

```
docker login -e dummy@example.com -p $(gcloud auth print-access-token) -u _token https://gcr.io
docker push [your-image]
```

Credits to mattmoor, more info in original answer here: 
[Access google container registry without the gcloud client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291576/access-google-container-registry-without-the-gcloud-client)

Comment: I found that in bash I have to wrap `$(gcloud auth print-access-token)` in double quotes for this to work, and it now works reliably. Thanks!

Comment: I get the same retry errors using this method. Did you find another way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same or similar problem. After a few minutes of retry loop depicted with screenshoot above, the command will fail with `net/http: TLS handshake timeout`.

The solution that fixed it for me was editing the docker daemon configuration  with

`DOCKER_OPTS="--max-concurrent-uploads=1"`

I had a feeling this issue was connected with docker clogging up the network, as I noticed even browsing to gmail can get a timeout(!)

Answer (score 1):

Switching to regular `docker push` doesn't help timeouts. This appears to be related to your ISP and uploading assets.

I was receiving the same error. After moving the Docker build process to the cloud (which has a much larger pipeline), gcloud docker builds and deploys the image just fine.