# Awaiting gcloud docker -- push

Tags: docker, gcloud

Im building a deployment script in nodejs, with 1 part being calling the gcloud cli through `require('child_process').spawn(...);` to push the already build docker images. i execute the following command:

```
gcloud docker -- push myImage
```

This all works great, the images gets uploaded. But the problem is that gcloud docker opens a new process to push my image and the process i spawned, closes before the pushing of the image is done.

Problem is, I want to delete the builded images locally, directly afterwards.

I've been looking in the [gcloud docker documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/docker) but i don't see any argument for this.

Is there a way to know that the process of uploading the images was completed?

edit:
i did find [a way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35603991/1275832) to do it only through docker but i'd like a universal solution (both working on windows and linux environments)

Answer (score 0):

After some more research on the google documentation, i found [this authentication page](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication)

They tell you to create a service account and use the json private key you get as token to use into `docker login`. This way you don't need an oauth token for your automated services, but you can use this json key instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can check all the images  by running this command:
[sudo docker images]
Take a note of the "IMAGE ID" it will used when Tagging and deleting the image.

When you build a docker images, tag it before By running this command:
[docker tag "IMAGE ID" gcr.io/{the Google Container Registry path}:{version} ]

You can push any built image by running this command: 
[gcloud docker -- push gcr.io/{the google container registry path}:{version}].

When pushing you will notice that list of container are pushed to your Google Container registry see the example below:

$ sudo gcloud docker -- push gcr.io/{the google container registry path}:{version}

The push refers to repository [gcr.io/{the google container registry path}]
43d35f91f441: =================> Pushed 
3b93beb428bf: Layer already exists 
629fa6a1373d: =================> Pushed 
0f82335d5733: Layer already exists 
c216b39a9ab6: Layer already exists 
ccbd0c2af699: Layer already exists 
38788b6810d3: Layer already exists 
cd7100a72410: Layer already exists 
v1: digest: sha256:**************************************************************** size: 1992

You can check all the images  by running this command:
[sudo docker images]

Take a note of the "IMAGE ID" of the image you need to delete.
Run the command : 
[sudo docker rmi "IMAGE ID"].

If the image doesn't allow to be deleted, you have to stop the container that is still running and prune the docker
[sudo docker container stop "the container ID"]
[sudo docker container prune]

Then you can delete the image.