# Creating image pull secret for google container registry that doesn't expire?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I'm trying to get Kubernetes to download images from a Google Container Registry from another project. According to the [docs](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/#specifying-imagepullsecrets-on-a-pod) you should create an image pull secret using:

```
$ kubectl create secret docker-registry myregistrykey --docker-server=DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER --docker-username=DOCKER_USER --docker-password=DOCKER_PASSWORD --docker-email=DOCKER_EMAIL
```

But I wonder what `DOCKER_USER` and `DOCKER_PASSWORD` I should use for authenticating with Google Container Registry? Looking at the [GCR docs](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/auth) it says that the password is the access token that you can get by running:

```
$ gcloud auth print-access-token
```

This actually works... for a while. The problem seems to be that this access token expires after (what I believe to be) one hour. I need a password (or something) that doesn't expire when creating my image pull secret. Otherwise the Kubernetes cluster can't download the new images after an hour or so. What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is really tricky but after a lot of trail and error I think I've got it working.

1. Go to the Google Developer Console > Api Manager > Credentials and click "Create credentials" and create a "service account key"
2. Under "service account" select new and name the new key "gcr" (let the key type be json)
3. Create the key and store the file on disk (from here on we assume that it was stored under `~/secret.json`)
4. Now login to GCR using Docker from command-line:

   `$ docker login -e your@email.se -u _json_key -p "$(cat ~/secret.json)" https://eu.gcr.io`

This will generate an entry for "https://eu.gcr.io" in your `~/.docker/config.json` file.
6. Copy the JSON structure under "https://eu.gcr.io" into a new file called "~/docker-config.json", remove newlines! For example:

7. Base64 encode this file:

   `$ cat ~/docker-config.json | base64`
8. This will print a long base64 encoded string, copy this string and paste it into an image pull secret definition (called `~/pullsecret.yaml`):

> ```
> apiVersion: v1
>   kind: Secret
>   metadata:
>     name: mykey
>   data:
>     .dockercfg: <paste base64 encoded string here>
>   type: kubernetes.io/dockercfg
> ```

9. Now create the secret:

`$ kubectl create -f ~/pullsecret.yaml`
10. Now you can use this pull secret from a pod, for example:

> ```
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: Pod
> metadata: 
>   name: foo
>   namespace: awesomeapps
> spec: 
>   containers: 
>     - image: "janedoe/awesomeapp:v1"
>       name: foo
>   imagePullSecrets: 
>     - name: mykey
> ```

or add it to a [service account](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/service-accounts/#adding-imagepullsecrets-to-a-service-account).

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I got very close but made the mistake of trying to use my existing `~/.docker/config` which already had gcr.io credentials, but I believe they were tied to the wrong service account... or something. Anyway, a couple notes: when creating the new service account (Step 2) I had to choose a Role, so I picked Project > Viewer, which seems to have worked. Also, with the `base64` command, you can remove the `cat` and should add `-w 0` to avoid newlines: `base64 -w 0 ~/docker-config.json`

Comment: Also, it appears that they've [changed the name of the Secret type from `dockercfg` to `dockerconfigjson`](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/), which is what I used. I'm on k8s 1.4.0.

Comment: Aand one more comment... in step 5, you left out the top-level `{ "auths":` json key. Removing the newlines from that file also isn't really necessary, but you do want to narrow down your docker config to only have the auth(s) you want copied to the Kubernetes secret.

Comment: This works great! Thanks! 
On step 4. the -e flag is deprecated in version v1.11.0 https://docs.docker.com/engine/deprecated/#/e-and---email-flags-on-docker-login

Comment: on Mac, if you inspect the config the credentials might be hidden behind osxkeychain. In order to see the credentials, go into docker preferences, disable "Securely store Docker  logins in max osx keychain", restart docker then follow the steps above agin.

Comment: The "Securely store Docker logins in max osx keychain" option does not seem to exist anymore so after the docker login step I edited `~/.docker/config.json` and manually removed the line referencing oskeychain". I then ran the docker login command again and voila, the auth token appeared in `~/.docker/config.json`

Answer (score 17):

It is much easier with kubectl

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry mydockercfg \
  --docker-server "https://eu.gcr.io" \
  --docker-username _json_key \
  --docker-email not@val.id \
  --docker-password=$(cat your_service_account.json)
```

One important detail after you download your_service_account.json from google is to ***join all the lines in the json into one row.*** For this you could replace `cat` with `paste`:

```
  --docker-password=$(paste -s your_service_account.json)
```

Comment: or, add quotes around the subshell invocation in `--docker-password="$(cat your_service_account.json)"`

Comment: means you can't put this in your yaml and then change it easily :(

Answer (score 5):

This answer ensures that only one set of docker credentials gets included in your Kubernetes secret, and handles trimming newlines for you.

Follow the same first three steps from Johan's great answer:

1. Go to the Google Developer Console > Api Manager > Credentials and click "Create credentials" and create a "service account key"
2. Under "service account" select new and name the new key "gcr" (let the key type be json)
3. Create the key and store the file on disk (from here on we assume that it was stored under `~/secret.json`)

Next, run these commands to generate and inject the required Docker credentials into your cluster:

```
export GCR_KEY_JSON=$(cat ~/secret.json | tr -d '\n')
mv ~/.docker/config.json ~/.docker/config-orig.json
cat >~/.docker/config.json <<EOL
{
  "auths": {
    "gcr.io": {}
  }
}
EOL
docker login --username _json_key --password "$GCR_KEY_JSON" https://gcr.io
export DOCKER_CONFIG_JSON_NO_NEWLINES=$(cat ~/.docker/config.json | tr -d '\n')
mv ~/.docker/config-orig.json ~/.docker/config.json
cat >secrets.yaml <<EOL
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: gcr-key
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: $(echo -n ${DOCKER_CONFIG_JSON_NO_NEWLINES} | base64 | tr -d '\n')
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson

EOL
kubectl create -f secrets.yaml
```

When you specify Pods that pull images from GCR, include the `gcr-key` secret name in your `spec` section:

```
spec:
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: gcr-key
  containers:
  - image: ...
```

Comment: This helped me massively, thank you. Just a heads up for anyone else, I went through this and was scratching my head as to why it didn't work, it was because our pods run in a non-default namespace and the key needs to be in the same namespace - define the namespace in metadata section of secrets.yaml. newbie error I know, but this might save someone else  the same pain.

Comment: This is the best method for now. You can even make it into a script!

Answer (score 2):

You can also grant the service account your cluster runs as access to the GCS bucket:

```
  eu.artifacts.{project-id}.appspot.com
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291576/access-google-container-registry-without-the-gcloud-client) answer has a few `gsutil` commands to make that happen.

Comment: Yes, the Google Cloud blog also mentions this: https://medium.com/google-cloud/using-single-docker-repository-with-multiple-gke-projects-1672689f780c

Answer (score 1):

From the [official ways](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication), you can:

```
$ docker login -e 1234@5678.com -u _json_key -p "$JSON_KEY" https://gcr.io
```

Note: The e-mail is not used, so you can put whatever you want in it.

Change `gcr.io` to whatever is your domain shown in your [Google Container Registry](https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images) (e.g. `eu.gcr.io`).

To get that `$JSON_KEY`:

1. Go to [API Manager > Credentials](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_)
2. Click "Create credentials" > **Service account key**:

   - Service account: New service account

     - Name: Anything you want, like `Docker Registry (read-only)`
     - Role: Storage (scroll down) > **Storage Object Viewer**
   - Key type: **JSON**
3. Download as `keyfile.json`
4. `JSON_KEY=$(cat keyfile.json | tr '\n' ' ')`
5. Now you can use it.

Once logged in you can just run `docker pull`. You can also copy the updated `~/.dockercfg` to preserve the settings.

Answer (score 1):

**No image pull secret is needed, it can be done by an IAM configuration**

I tried other answers but I can't get the Image Pull Secret approach working.

However I found that this can be done by Granting access to the **Compute Engine default service account** in the project where the Kubernetes cluster is. This service account was created automatically by GCP.

As described here:
https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#granting_users_and_other_projects_access_to_a_registry

You need to execute the following command to grant access to the Cloud Storage bucket serving the Container Registry

```
gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:[EMAIL-ADDRESS]:objectViewer gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```

**BUCKET_NAME:**

```
artifacts.[PROJECT-ID].appspot.com for images pushed to gcr.io/[PROJECT-ID], or
[REGION].artifacts.[PROJECT-ID].appspot.com, where [REGION] is:
us for registry us.gcr.io
eu for registry eu.gcr.io
asia for registry asia.gcr.io
```

**EMAIL-ADDRESS:**

```
The email address of the service account called: **Compute Engine default service account** in the GCP project where the Kubernetes cluster run
```