# Unable to pull docker image into Kubernetes Pod from Google Container Registry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry

I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36283660/creating-image-pull-secret-for-google-container-registry-that-doesnt-expire?answertab=votes#tab-top) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926813/pull-private-docker-images-from-google-container-registry-w-o-gcloud), and created my Kubernetes secret for Google Container Registry using a service account JSON key with project: owner and viewer permissions.  I have also verified that the image does in fact exist in Google Container Registry by going to the console.

I have also read this [document](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/images/#using-a-private-registry).

When I run:

```
minikube dashboard
```

And then from the user interface, I click the "+" sybmol, specify the URL of my image like this:

```
project-123456/bot-image
```

then click on 'advanced options' and specify the Secret that was imported.

After a few seconds I see this error:

```
Error: Status 403 trying to pull repository project-123456/bot-image: "Unable to access the repository: project-123456/bot-image; please verify that it exists and you have permission to access it (no valid credential was supplied)."
```

If I look at what's inside the Secret file (.dockerconfigjson), it's like:
{"https://us.gcr.io": {"email": "admin@domain.com", "auth": "longtexthere"}}

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 3):

The json needs to have a top level `"{auths":` json key from:

[Creating image pull secret for google container registry that doesn't expire?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36283660/creating-image-pull-secret-for-google-container-registry-that-doesnt-expire?answertab=votes#comment68160959_36286707)

So the json should be structured like:

`{"auths":{"https://us.gcr.io": {"email": "admin@domain.com", "auth": "longtexthere"}}}`

If you are still having issues, you can alternatively download the latest version of minikube (0.17.1) and run 
`minikube addons configure registry-creds` 
following the prompts there to setup creds
then run `minikube addons enable registry-creds`

Now you should be able to pull down pods from GCR using a yaml structured like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: foo
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
    - image: gcr.io/example-vm/helloworld:latest
      name: foo
```

EDIT: 6/13/2018 updating the commands to reflect comment by @Rambatino

Comment: thanks Aaron.  I downloaded .17.1, enabled registry-creds with GCR and imported the JSON key.  It reported "registry-creds was successfully enabled" but when I try to create a deployment with the GCR image it still fails, and doesn't populate any new Secrets.

Comment: Make sure that you didn't get the error: 
`Could not read file for application_default_credentials.json`

Also can you verify that an ImagePullSecret was created with:
`kubectl describe serviceaccount`

Also did you add the gcr prefix to your image?  I added an example pod spec that is working to my original answer.

Comment: did you end up resolving this issue?  if it is easier, you can also post an issue on github: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube

Comment: The enable registry-creds has been split into two commands: `minikube addons configure registry-creds && minikube addons enable registry-creds` (https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1391)