# using gcloud docker client on coreos

Tags: docker, gcloud, coreos

Can I use the 'gcloud docker' client on coreos? I want to do pull a container, but when I do

> gcloud docker pull

I get

```
WARNING: 'docker' was not discovered on the path. Credentials have been stored, but are not guaranteed to work with the 1.11 Docker client ifan external credential store is configured.
```

Can I install a full-fledged gcloud client? And where is gcloud anyway? I can run it, but `which gcloud` comes back empty handed.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291576/access-google-container-registry-without-the-gcloud-client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use this command:

`$ docker login -e 1234@5678.com -u _token -p "$(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://gcr.io`

You can also change the `https://gcr.io` to e.g.: `https://us.gcr.io` if your image is stored somewhere else.

If this not works, try the JSON Keyfile Method it is more reliable.

`docker login -e 1234@5678.com -u _json_key -p "$(cat keyfile.json)" https://gcr.io`

It is also documented here:

https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication