# Sharing docker registry images among gcloud projects

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

We're hoping to use a google project to share docker images containing microservices across projects.

I was thinking I could do it using the kubernetes run command and pull an image from a project other than the current one:

```
kubectl run  gdrive-service --image=us.gcr.io/foo/gdrive-service
```

My user credentials have access to both projects. However, it seems like the run command can only pull mages from the current project.

Is there an approach for doing this?  It seems like an obvious use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options here.

1. Use `_json_key` auth described [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#using_a_json_key_file) with Kubernetes pull secrets.
2. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291576/access-google-container-registry-without-the-gcloud-client) describes how to add robots across projects as well, still without needing pull secrets.

Comment: Hmm, the first seems to mean passing around a copy of the json file with the service account. Will look into the latter approach a bit later.

Comment: Not ideal, but this is the way it goes.

Answer (score 1):

In my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45552830/2800118) I describe a way to do this by granting the GKE service account user `Storage Object Viewer` permission under the project that contains the registry.