# Using Google Container Registry from GKE in another project

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

How can a GKE cluster pull container images from a Container Registry hosted in another project?

I have a GKE cluster in project `<reader-project>` trying to access a GCR image in project `<registry-project>`.

I've tried adding the GCE service account email for `<reader-project>` as a User with Reader access on the storage bucket in `<registry-project>`, but I'm still getting the error:

```
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access denied.</Message>
<Details>Caller does not have storage.objects.get access to object us.artifacts.<registry-project>.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:<tag>.
</Details></Error>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add GCE service account email as a User with Storage Object Viewer role. It gives the service account Read-Only access to GCS objects(container images) in your project.

Comment: Is it possible to add a bunch of project service account emails under one IAM role so that I can grant other permissions to that group as well? Looks like it should be, but I already tried that approach for Storage Viewer and it didn't work.

Comment: yeah, that should be fine.

Comment: This does not work now. I tried by adding the compute engine service account of different project to the project containing registry. I still get 403 error.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the IAM permissions of the project under which you have your GKE and you will see a user similar to: `123456789-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`.

Then in your container registry project, grant that user the `Storage Object Viewer permission`. Your GKE will then be allowed to pull images from th

Answer (score 0):

Can you run the following commands to check the permissions for both buckets:

gsutil acl get gs://us.artifacts..appspot.com

gsutil acl get gs://artifacts..appspot.com

artifacts..appspot.com is the default bucket. When you add the service account as Storage Object Viewer, read-only permission of the default bucket is granted.

Here is the link about gsutil tool:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/acl