# Accessing GCR from a VM of different project

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Assume I have two projects like [GCR-project] and [read-project]. I want to pull images stored in GCR in [GCR-project] from a VM in [read-project]

I have already referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291576/access-google-container-registry-without-the-gcloud-client), but did not work. I tried two ways namely,

**1. Adding service account to IAM:**

I added [read-project]'s VM service account mail to [GCR-project] with role set to Storage > Storage Object Viewer. Now, trying to pull docker container in [read-project]'s VM using the command

```
docker pull asia.gcr.io/<GCR-project-id>/<folder>/<container-name>
```

failed with **403**. I also tried this command:

```
gcloud docker pull asia.gcr.io/sharedproject-156002/em/textextractor:8-jre-p4
```

which also failed with **403**. I tried upgrading the role to editor role to the service account in IAM. After this also, docker pull command failed with **403**.

**2. Adding service account to gsutil acl:**

All GCR repositories are actually cloud storage buckets. So, I tried editing the bucket acl to allow read permissions for the [read-project]'s VM service account by using the command:

```
gsutil acl ch -u <service-account-mailID>:R gs://artifacts.$PROJECT_ID.appspot.com
```

After this trying out docker pull command also failed with 403.

How to pull docker images from VM of different project? I would also like to know to access docker images in GCR from VM other than GCP like AWS.

Comment: Could be a lot of things, but a first guess is that your instance lacks a necessary scope. Use the command in the question you referenced to check: `curl -H 'Metadata-Flavor: Google' $SVC_ACCT/scopes`. Also be aware that the instance's default credentials will only include scopes specified when the instance was created. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes

Comment: Oh I get that!! May be after specifying the service account, I think I need to create another instance and check it out!! @BrandonYarbrough That was a good catch bro!! Will check it out and let you know.