# Google compute and servicce account for registry access

Tags: docker, gitlab, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-container-registry

I' ve got a private gitlab host and want to add some runners on gcp.
So, I've:

- create a service account (with Editor rights on the project)
- create a compute instance (named `gitlab-runner`) with Ubuntu 16.04 on it and the service account associated.
- install `gitlab-runner` / `kubectl` / `docker-ce` on it
- register a runner of type `shell`
- register a runner of type `docker`

The runner shell have no problem what so ever.

The runner docker ? well... works with something like this

```
exemple:
  stage: build
  image: google/cloud-sdk:latest
  tags:
    - runner-docker
  script:
    - # do something here
```

My problem is when I want to use an image I previously build like this:

```
exemple2:
  stage: build
  image: eu.gcr.io/project/image_name:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
  tags:
    - runner-docker
  script:
    - # do something here
```

When I do this, gitlab-runner can't pull the image.

So, I've tried somehting like this: [Access google container registry without the gcloud client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291576/access-google-container-registry-without-the-gcloud-client)

Then, whene I connect to the `gitlab-runner` (via ssh) I've no problem doing a pull.

But the runner can't.

Any idea what going wrong ?

---

I've done a temporay gitlab-ci.yml like this:

```
stage:
  - build
  - test

variables:
  CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"

test_gcloud_shell:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - shell
  before_script:
    - echo "disable before script"
  script:
    - docker run --rm eu.gcr.io/project/image_name:latest

test_gcloud_docker:
  stage: test
  image: eu.gcr.io/project/image_name:latest
  tags:
    - docker
  before_script:
    - echo "disable before script"
  script:
    - echo "hello"
```

The task `test_gcloud_shell` work without any problem, but not `test_gcloud_docker`.
Any id ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you set `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG`? See [GitLab's docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#using-a-private-container-registry) and [a similar issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2015).

You probably need to use the service account's [JSON key file](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#using_a_json_key_file) if you want long-lived credentials.

Comment: `.dockercfg` and `.docker/config` have ~50 lines all (from `.docker/config`) copied to `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` in `my config.toml`.

I've reboot the machine after that and it's not still not working...